# Getting string instead of Carbon Object when fetching data

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I have a date and time input field, I'm merging both my date and time fields together and trying to store those 2 values in the database.

**Problem:** When I retrieve the date from my database, I get the date in a string instead of an Carbon object. Why is this?

**What I have:**

My input fields:

```
{{Form::date('date', \Carbon\Carbon::today(),['class' => 'form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0'])}}
{{Form::time('time', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/Brussels'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

My Store function at the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this ->validate($request, ['title' => 'required|max:25','description' => 'required|max:60']);

    $task = new Task;
    $task -> end_date = $request->input('date') . ' ' . $request->input('time');
    $task -> user_id = auth()->id();
    $task->save();

    return redirect('/tasks')->with('success', 'Task created');
}
```

My Model where I set the attribute:

```
    class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','description', 'end-date'];

    protected $dates = ['end_date'];

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function setEndDateAttribute($date) 
    {

        $this->attributes['end_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);

    }
    public function getEndDateAttribute($date) 
    {
       dd($date);
       // Result of this example: "2018-08-17 22:39:55"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you add:

```
protected $dates = ['end_date'];
```

You don't need the mutators anymore.

You can simply call the attribute:

```
$task = Task::first();
dd($task->end_date);
```

Comment: So the setEndDateAttribute() can be deleted aswell?

Comment: If you're using the default DATETIME format, yes. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-casting